# Fat-free get data from PUT request

Tags: php, rest, fat-free-framework

I have a PUT request from frontend side. I use F3 framework on backend side and want to parse params from query. How can I do that?
GET, POST requests work fine.

```
$f3->get('GET'); //works
$f3->get('POST'); //works
$f3->get('PUT'); //does not work
```

I found a solution with using REQBODY as a param, but it does not work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

PUT comes in BODY as raw

```
$f3->get('BODY');
```

Comment: That's the correct answer. You can parse it like this: `parse_str($f3->BODY,$input);`